# Какой код для картинки должен быть в xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, html5, xslt

Нашел код для xsl для картинки. А какой должен быть код в xml для картинки
Или вообще как записать в xml and xsl код для картинки

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
      <xsl:value-of select="image/@uri" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="title">
      <xsl:value-of select="image/@title" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="width">150</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="height">150</xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Comment: Вообще-то, код преобразования пишется для существующих данных, а не наоборот. Посмотрите [ревизии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/435134/revisions) вопроса в теме, где вы "нашли" этот код xsl. Там есть xml.